# Convert hex string to integer

Tags: java, string, hex

HI I want to get exact integer value from hex string.

My problem is I have an integer value as `-25` and its hex String is "E7"

but when I convert -25 using

```
public static String toHexString(int i) {

    String hexString = Integer.toHexString(i);
    if (hexString.length() % 2 != 0) {
        hexString = "0" + hexString;
    }

    return hexString.toUpperCase();
}
```

the above function It returns "FFFFE7"

and when I convert it to get decimal value which is `231` using

```
int len =Integer.parseInt(Hex,16);
```

I get  Error "Invalid Int"

but when I convert it to integer value manually as

```
  int len =Integer.parseInt("E7",16);
```

I get result as 231.

so can anyone tell me how can I get exact integer by passing whole hexadecimal string ??

as my hex string is dynamic so i can't fix it .

Comment: -25 in hexadecimal is FFFFE7 only...so your program is correct.check it http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(-25);
        System.out.println("hex is :: " + hex);
        int n = (int) Long.parseLong(hex, 16);
        System.out.println("int is :: " + n);
    }
```

**Output**

```
hex is :: ffffffe7
int is :: -25
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i already did it . but i dnt want -25 again i want integer value 231 which is of hex string E7...

Comment: @NehaShukla quetsion is not clear. refer my output and then let us know.

Comment: @NehaShukla y considering `E7` only from `ffffffe7`

Comment: as Integer.toHexString(-25) returns hex string with pre added F and I cant remove this from result

Comment: @NehaShukla i am still wondering, `hex representation` of `-25` is `ffffffe7`, what you want to consider when converting back to int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63324/discussion-between-ankur-singhal-and-neha-shukla).

Answer (score 0):

Since number is negative,It will overflows. `Integer.parseInt()` takes a `signed int`, while `toHexString()` produces an `unsigned` result.

You should use `Long.parseLong(hex, 16);`

Eg:

```
 String hex = Integer.toHexString(-25);
 System.out.println(hex);
 try {
   int len =Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
   System.out.println(len);
 }catch (NumberFormatException e){
   System.out.println("Number format exception");
 }
 int val = (int) Long.parseLong(hex, 16);
 System.out.println(val);
```

Out put:

```
 ffffffe7
 Number format exception
 -25
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i already did it . but i dnt want -25 again i want integer value 231 which is of hex string E7...